# nlp.update issue with Spacy 3.0: TypeError: [E978] The Language.update method takes a list of Example objects, but got: {<class 'tuple'>}

Tags: python, nlp, spacy-3

With Spacy version 3.0 there seem to be some changes with nlp.update.
I am utterly confused with this simple code:

```
examples = TRAIN_DATA
random.shuffle(examples)
losses = {}
    
for batch in minibatch(examples, size=8):
    nlp.update(batch, sgd=optimizer, drop=0.35, losses=losses)
```

When I do type(batch) it indicates that batch is of type list. But the error message says it is a tuple. I also tried to convert it to a list without success. What am I doing wrong?

The exact error is:

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
22
23         for batch in minibatch(examples, size=8):
---> 24             nlp.update(batch, sgd=optimizer, drop=0.35, losses=losses)
25
26         print("Losses ({}/{})".format(epoch + 1, epochs), losses)

~/nlp_learn/statbot/.statbot/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/language.py in update(self, examples, _, drop, sgd, losses, component_cfg, exclude)
1090         if len(examples) == 0:
1091             return losses
-> 1092         validate_examples(examples, "Language.update")
1093         examples = _copy_examples(examples)
1094         if sgd is None:

~/nlp_learn/statbot/.statbot/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/training/example.pyx in spacy.training.example.validate_examples()

TypeError: [E978] The Language.update method takes a list of Example objects, but got: {<class 'tuple'>}

Here the first line of TRAIN_DATA as an example:
('Auf Bauer Lehmanns Hof wird an beiden Pfingsttagen Brot im Backofen gebacken.',
{'entities': [(10, 18, 'PER')]})

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to convert `TRAIN_DATA` to `Example` type. Probably the easiest way is using `Example.from_dict()` method.

```
TRAIN_DATA = # your data
random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
losses = {}
for batch in minibatch(TRAIN_DATA, size=8):
    for text, annotations in batch:
        doc = nlp.make_doc(text)
        example = Example.from_dict(doc, annotations)
        nlp.update([example], drop=0.35, sgd=optimizer, losses=losses)
```

Comment: from spacy.training import Example

Comment: Thanks for the solution!

But like that it can't be trained in MultiProcessing. Do you have any info on what needs to be changed so that it works?